# Obtener registros de tres tablas de varios a varios

Tags: mysql, sql, relaciones

Quiero obtener los registros de las tablas `pago_persona` y `recarga_persona` que estén asociados a la tabla `persona`, con X `id`.

***___TABLAS___***

**pago_persona:** [id_pago_persona, id_persona, valor]

**recarga_persona:** [id_recarga_persona, id_persona, valor]

**persona:** [id_persona, nombre]

---

Quiero traer los registros de los `pagos` y las `recargas` vinculadas a esta persona, que quede de esta forma:

**Nombre** | **Tipo** | **Valor** |

Daniel    | Recarga   | $12.000

Daniel | Pago | $5.000

Daniel | Pago | $7.200

Daniel | Recarga | $5.000

Daniel | Pago | $6.500

etc.....

De momento, intenté con lo siguiente:

```
SELECT
 rp.id_recarga_persona,
 rp.valor,
 p.nombre,
 pp.id_pago_persona,
 pp.valor
FROM
 persona p
INNER JOIN
 recarga_persona rp
ON
 p.id_persona = rp.id_persona
INNER JOIN
 pago_persona pp
ON
 p.id_persona = pp.id_persona
WHERE id_persona = 5;
```

El punto es que se NO soy muy bueno en `SQL` y me confundo con al momento de traer datos de otras tablas, ya intenté con `INNER JOIN` pero no me arroja el resultado que deseo.

Si alguien porfavor tiene ideas o sugerencias, o sabe cómo lograr lo que quiero, le agradecería un montón.

Comment: Agrega la consulta que has tratado hasta el momento

Comment: una disculpa, estoy revisando las tablas que manejas, ¿quieres que la consulta identifique de donde proviene para indicar el tipo, y el valor de la tabla? ya que solamente veo IDs en cada tabla, indicando la correlacion con la tabla persona, no veo que en tus tablas tengas el valor. (como al momento has explicado)

Comment: Correcto @fearteck, quiero que la consulta me identifique en la columna `accion` si probiene de la tabla `pago_persona` o `recarga_persona`.

Comment: Como recomendación, te faltaría una fecha para que te lo agrupe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT nombre, tipo, valor, fecha
FROM (
  SELECT 1 type, p.nombre,  'Recarga' tipo, pp.valor, pp.fecha 
  FROM persona p JOIN pago_persona pp
  ON p.id_persona= pp.id_persona
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2 type, p.nombre,  'Pago' tipo, r.valor, r.fecha 
  FROM persona p JOIN recarga_persona r
  ON p.id_persona= r.id_persona
) t
ORDER BY fecha, nombre, type;
```

Puedes ver este [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kTWLQ5uaTFg6mz3uvuaULG/0) para ver como se comporta usando `type` y agrupando por fechas

Comment: Genial, me funcionó a la perfección. Sólo no entendí una cosa de tu SQL, a qué se refiere `1 type` y `2 type` en cada `SELECT`?

Comment: es para indicar la columna, se puede obviar y sacar, pero para ser más practico en uniones sirven mucho. 1 es columna persona unida al pago y el 2 es persona unida a la recarga.

Answer (score 1):

Saca ambos por separado y luego los unes

```
select p.nombre, 'Recarga' tipo, rp.valor from persona p
join recarga_persona rp
on rp.id_persona = p.id_persona
union all
select p.nombre, 'Pago' tipo, pp.valor from persona p
join pago_persona pp
on pp.id_persona = p.id_persona
```

Comment: Pero ese union no le va a mostrar los valores en forma vertical?, digo por que en la pregunta el trata de verlos de forma horizontal

Comment: En el ejemplo de salida que puso, pide los datos en forma vertical, horizontal seria pivoteado, si es que entiendo bien tus terminos de vertical y horizontal.